# Serverless Framework with lambda-proxy integation and API Model Validation

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I have an issue validating a request with a model when the user changes the content-type of the request in a [serverless framework](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#example-lambda-event-before-customization) lambda-proxy integration
As per AWS docs, we can not change too much when using [lambda-proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html)

For example, the [passthrough behavior](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integration-passthrough-behaviors.html) that explains what happens when a validation model does not match the request type, can not be used on lambda-proxy integration.

My problem: I want to reject all requests that are not JSON so they must be forced to use the model validation. But at the same time, I do not want to change the integration type from lambda-proxy to lambda.

What can I do to solve this issue?

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is inspect the headers in the event object to confirm that it is the type you expect and if not return an error:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html

Answer (score 1):

We can enforce the **Content-Type** header straight into the API Gateway like below.
[image]

References can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html